# Running MVC 4 Web Application, URL Without having Application Pool Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC 4 web application and it is working fine. I have to route the URL that is done by URL Routing in Route.config in App_start.

The URL of the Web Application contains the name of Application Pool Made in IIS 7 and I don't want that coming up in the URL.

Example: 
Current URL: http://www.myAppDomain.com/AppPoolName/PageID/PageTitle/

Desired URL: http://www.myAppDomain.com/PageID/PageTitle/

The Problem is the application is not working if I remove the Application pool name by URL routing.

Is there any way that I can hide the Application Pool Name from URL and make the application working.

Any Suggestion with Example would be Appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set wwwroot folder for your www.myAppDomain.com to folder where your application is being deployed (e.g. c:\myapp\wwwroot{appfiles}).
This can be done by clicking on site and clicking basic settings button on right pane. You will get dialog where you can sett app root folder.